# JQuery: create array from element's name and create list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to getElement's names => make an array => create a menu as list => add some clickbehaviour CSS. When exercising I already found a way to get all elements but could not reach their names.
The elements I am aiming for look like this `<a class="jqsubmenu" name="ELEMENTSNAME"></a>`.

The HTML-Code to be produced needs to be like `<div id="#submenu"><ul>...</ul></div>`. The `<li>` needs to look like `<li><a href="#ELEMENTSNAME">ELEMENTSNAME</a></li>`. When a menu item is clicked any "active" classes in #submenu need to be removed and the clicked Anchor gets class="active".

Here are my results where I got stuck:

**1) Get elements:**

```
var optionTexts = [];
$("A.jqsubmenu").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
```

**2) make list** (once I hopefully have an array) and write into DOM

```
   var SubmenuArray = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
    // GENERATE SUBMENU
        var ObjUl = $('<div id="submenu"><ul></ul></div>');
        for (i = 0; i < SubmenuArray.length; i++)
        {
            var Objli = $('<li></li>');
            var Obja = $('<a href="#ARRAYITEM">ARRAYITEM</a>');

        }       // WRITE INTO DOM
        $('#submenuwrap').append(ObjUl);
    }
```

**3) CSS-Gimmick**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#submenu A" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#submenu A" ).removeClass("active");
        $( this ).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Thanks for your answers and all the best!

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

To access element's name attribute use

```
$("A.jqsubmenu").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).attr("name")) });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! When I use the code in the browserconcole it returns the same array as mine: [
<a class=​"jqsubmenu" name=​"One">​</a>​
, 
<a class=​"jqsubmenu" name=​"Two">​</a>​
, 
<a class=​"jqsubmenu" name=​"Three">​</a>​
]
What I was hoping to get is ['One','Two','Three']